# select all records from left table that do not exist in right table

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, left-join, temp-tables, isnull

I am working on sql server I have two tables and   I need to return records from the left table which are not found in the right table for that  I am using left join like below query,

```
select @MID=MID,@MName=Name,@PID=PID,@PName=PName,@DID=DID from @CompanyDataInfo where id=@MCount


insert into #temp SELECT  Top(1) f.Name,f.PID,f.PName,v.* FROM  @CompanyDataInfo f 
  left join  Employee v on  v.Id=f.ID and v.DID=f.DID 
  where  v.Id =@MID and v.DId = @DId and v.PId = @PId and v.CId =@CId and DATE_TIME between DATEADD(minute,-555,GETDATE()) and GETDATE() order by DATE_TIME desc
```

Result should be  all rows  from  @CompanyDataInfo table while no record  found in Employee table for related ID, I googled and use "v.Id  is null"  but not getting expected result

Is there any solution greatly appriciable

Thanks In advance

Comment: And when you googled your title with 'sql', what did you learn?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not using `left join` in correct way. You are using your right table reference in where clause. I try to correct it below but I don't have full information about your table schema. Please try this-

```
select
    @MID        = MID,
    @MName      = Name,
    @PID        = PID,
    @PName      = PName,
    @DID        = DID
from @CompanyDataInfo
where id = @MCount

insert into #temp
select
    f.Name,
    f.PID,
    f.PName,
    v.*
from @CompanyDataInfo f
left join  Employee v on v.Id=f.ID and v.DID=f.DID
where   f.Id = @MID and
        f.DId = @DId and
        f.PId = @PId and
        f.CId = @CId and
        f.DATE_TIME between DATEADD(minute,-555,GETDATE()) and GETDATE() and
        v.Id is null
order by f.DATE_TIME desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `...and v.Id is null` to your `where` clause.

Comment: Yes, I used 'v.Id is null' but its not working for me.